# Multiview control lost selected view after postback

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2013, multiview

I have a problem with the control MultiView. I create a webpart for SharePoint 2013 that has a user control. In it I have one Multiview with a few View. Problem affects postback. Each time you postback choice view is reset, for example, I'm on view 3 and I click the button. Changes in view 3 are preserved, but MultiView has not set the selected view. Anyone know what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Save the current active index view in the hidden field on the page or viewstate value and the, during page_load set the active view taking it from this hidden field. that the best I can figure out.

Comment: I can share the sample which I have done in the morning to check it out. I have used SessionState, it works fine on SharePoint 2013. With 2010 version this is not required. Moreover, using event ActiveIndexChanged on MultiView will not work for this purpose. Hope that helps.